# How can I transfer the data from on column to another based on another column values in SQL

Tags: sql

```sql
select Products, Fiscal_year, Fiscal_Period, Stock_QTY, DaysRemaining,
       (Stock_QTY / DaysRemaining) as QtyforPeriod, 
       Stock_QTY -(Stock_QTY / DaysRemaining)  as LeftforNextmonth
from Stocks
```

```
products| Fiscal_yaer| Fiscal_period| Stock_QTY |DaysReamain| QtyforPeriod |LeftforNextMonth
5000           22            1           100           4                    
6000           22            1           200           4                     
7000           22            2           300           20         
7000           22            3           400           40
8000           23            1           500           60
5000           23            1           600           60
7000           23            2           700           90
8000           23            3           800           100
```

There is any possibility to write a query if the Fiscal_yae =22 Fiscal_period=4.  Subtract StockTY - LeftforNextMonth of period 3 and divided by DaysRemaining.

Like if the Fiscal_yae =22 Fiscal_period=5. Subtract StockTY - LeftforNextMonth of period 4 and divided by days remaining.

Like if the Fiscal_yae =22 Fiscal_period=6. Subtract StockTY ( - ) LeftforNextMonth of period 5 and divided by days remaining.

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. [[tag:mysql]], and [[tag:sq-server]] are *completely* different products.

Comment: Yes this is possible. In MySQL it would be something like `UPDATE Stocks SET QtyforPeriod = (StockTY - LeftforNextMonth) / DaysRemaining WHERE Fiscal_year = 22 AND Fiscal_period = 6`. Your current queries have multiple typos, so my query here may not work if you copy/paste, but that's the gist of it. You define which column you want to update, the calculated values, and the `WHERE` condition to determine which rows get this update.

Comment: if the fiscal_yar =22 and Fiscal_period = 6  cloumn-6, copy values from fiscal_yar =22 and Fiscal_period = 5 cloumn 7 values  into  fiscal_yar =22 and Fiscal_period = 6  column 6  but wont be change previous cloumn values. like the following period